# Does Azure CDN support stale-while-revalidate caching?

Tags: azure, cdn

1. Does Azure CDN support the [`stale-while-revalidate` and `stale-while-error`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Cache-Control#Expiration) (and `immutable`, out of curiosity) directives of the `Cache-Control` HTTP header? These directives are not standardised and both Internet Explorer and pre-Chromium Edge have no support for them.
2. If not, does Azure CDN provide another mechanism to implement [stale-while-revalidate caching behaviour](https://www.infoq.com/news/2020/11/ux-stale-while-revalidate/)?

Comment: This would probably be better handled by the Webmasters stack. https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft answer in 2021:

> Currently we do not support stale and revalidate feature and there
> are no plans to support it yet

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/316956/azure-cdn-should-respect-origin-cache-control.html#answer-346428